# How to sign a Hyperledger Fabric transaction at web application client side?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to design a Hyperledger Fabric solution with following requirements

1. The users are signed-up with an organization
2. The user should however have their individual identities on Blockchain
3. The users would interact with Blockchain through a web application
4. The users should store their own private keys / certificates
5. Individual user's key / certificate should be used to sign the transaction going to Blockchain. The organization however should not have access to user's private key / certificate
6. Instead the web application should merely transfer the signed content of the transaction to Blockchain, making it tamper-proof

Are there any solutions available that would cater to these requirements, so that the users continue to work through the web application only?
Can node.js SDK for Fabric be used on the client side to sign the transaction using the locally stored private key / certificate on user's desktop / laptop?

Comment: You could use an electron desktop application that 'lives' purely on the client and uses the nodejs sdk. This should suffice all your requirements, albeit not being a web app but a desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, no, there are no solutions available to cater to these requirements as the node SDK does not currently support a separation of logic between signing transaction proposals and sending transaction proposals. Step 6 is not possible with the 1.2 SDK.

Separating that logic is slated for the 1.3 release.

Comment: Has this become reality in the meantime?

Comment: Would be nice to know if this has happened in the meantime or still outstanding?